Recognizing face poset of a polyhedral complex
Consider a polyhedral complex $\mathcal{P}$. This means that $\mathcal{P}$ is collection of polytopes such that every face of a polytope in $\mathcal{P}$ is also contained in $\mathcal{P}$ and a nonempty intersection of any two polytopes is a face of both.
To $\mathcal{P}$ we can associate its face poset $\mathcal{F}$ consisting of elements of $\mathcal{P}$ where for $x, y \in \mathcal{F}$ we set $x < y$ when $x$ is a face of $y$. I think that $\mathcal{F}$ determines $\mathcal{P}$ uniquely, because it records how polytopes of $\mathcal{P}$ are glued to one another.
Now conversely, given an arbitrary poset $\mathcal{F}$, how to check whether it is a face poset for some polyhedral complex $\mathcal{P}$?

What do you already know about the problem? What have you figured out? What research have you done so far? A few things that occur to me are that any element of $\cal F$ at height 1  must be above exactly two minimals and that any element at height 2 must be above the same number of elements at heights 1 and 0. Can these ideas be generalized to elements at arbitrary heights (potential faces of higher dimension), and would the union of all such constraints suffice?
